# Delete categories recursively raises datareader exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have very basic category model `ID, RootCategoryID, Name` and if I have category that has many childrens it won't delete so I need to do this recursively but when I do so I get error.

I know that there is a work-around if I add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in connection string but AFAIK this can be solved from within code and it is not a good idea to use this parameter. Is this true?

### Error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

### Code

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    this.DeleteRecursive(id);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("index", "category");
}

private void DeleteRecursive(int id)
{
    // Selecting current category
    var currentCategory = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == id).Single(); // this line
    var childrenCategories = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.RootCategory.ID == id);

    // Check if category has children
    if (childrenCategories.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Loop through children and apply same function recrusively
        foreach (var c in childrenCategories)
        {
            this.DeleteRecursive(c.ID);
        }
    }

    // Category has no children left, delete it
    _db.Categories.Remove(currentCategory);
}
```

Comment: A recursive CTE would be more appropriate than LINQ for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaving the `DataReader` open for the `childrenCategories` statement.

Apart from the exception, it means you're executing the query twice - once to get the count and then again to get the data.

This should fix the problems:

```
var childrenCategories = _db.Categories
  .Where(x => x.RootCategory.ID == id)
  .ToList()
;
```

This executes the SQL statement and materializes all the records into a `List`.

So, you have your data in memory, and the `DataReader` is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that you are trying to chage the collaction during a `foreach` loop, this cannot be done.

try creating a List of items to be deleted and then delete them all with one

```
_db.Remove(itemsToRemove).
```

That would do the for you trick  .